# twitter Bootstrap sub navigation change color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

How do I change or override the color of sub navigation items in twitter bootstraps sub menu when viewed on mobile.

If you view this site via mobile: `http://61.8.186.105/` and select a top level menu, you will see that the sub nav is grey.  I need to make it white, but having no luck.

I tried overriding the bootstrap settings with:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #fff;
    }
}
```

.. but it is jus not picking it up.

If I set this style outside of the media query it works, (but I only want this color to set for max-width: 767px).

Anyone managed to succesfully change the color of this sub nav?

Thanks

Jason

Comment: `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `!important` in css, so that forcefully this css will be applied to link

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #fff !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rubyist, but this doesn't fix it either.  I don't think the problem is with the cascading of styles, I think it is with the media query.  If I take the style declaration out of the media query it overrides fine, but inside the media query, I can't see the style declaration anywhere when viewing the element with chrome tools.. the style just isn't getting included when inside the media query.  Thanks again. Jason

Comment: Okay, that's something strange. Let me try again. Thanks for the reply